# DAC output is completely dependent on Vreff?

Tags: dac

I want to generate unipolar and bipolar output voltages 0-10V and +/-10V respectively.

I am thinking of using AD5752R for this purpose, my requirements meets with this particular DAC.

My doubt is that in test conditions he has mentioned with Vreff=2.5V the DAC can produce 0-10V and +/-10.3V.

Can we Produce higher outputs than the Vreff ?

Datasheet: https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5722R_5732R_5752R.pdf

Comment: why would it not be able to output voltages higher than Vref ? ..... look at fig 45 to see how it is usef

Comment: Because I saw some Texas Instruments DAC chips whose output is with respect to Vref. For example DAC7714  Datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/dac7714.pdf

Comment: that is a different device

Comment: i don't understand why you do not believe the technical documentation sheets

Comment: I am using this chip to design a new board, so I am being just careful mate!

Comment: makes sense ... measure twice, cut once ... lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah the Vref = 2.5 V and the DAC can produce voltage output not more than the Vref, but if you see the datasheet on page 4 under Power requirement section,

[image]

In the table on can see the voltage range is 4.5 and 16.5 V for AVdd and AVss i.e when you configure the DAC this input of analog voltages are used to give an analog output range of

```
AVss < Analog Voltage Output < AVdd
```

i.e this is the analog reference voltage you should see when saying that the output analog voltage cannot exceed the reference voltage.

On the DAC you have to apply those voltages which you are mentioning to 'generate', to generate those voltages use a boost convertor, voltage multiplier etc....

Comment: I think that really addresses the core of the question. The IC doesn't magically produce higher voltages than what it is supplied with. On the other hand, the reference doesn't have to have the same range as the output, it only needs to be stable.

Comment: yeah, as stable as possible :D
you know TI, ST microelectronics etc have many online PDFs regarding this topic...one can check those out for more info....

Comment: @Divyam  Can you share those links?

Comment: [Understanding Data Converters](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa013/slaa013.pdf),

[Choose right ADC/DAC](https://www.ti.com/europe/downloads/Choose%20the%20right%20data%20converter%20for%20your%20application.pdf),

[Get best ADC performance](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/group0/3f/4c/a4/82/bd/63/4e/92/CD00211314/files/CD00211314.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00211314.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

AD5752R has configurable output amplifier. So while you have 2.5 V reference you can have higher output range.

Comment: So you' re saying that DAC can produce according to configured configuration regardless of Vref?

Comment: DAC can produce only voltage up to 2.5 V. But this chip has built in amplifier so it can be configured to change that to say 10 V output range. AD5752R contains DAC + configurable amplifier.